# Clion. Можно ли создать windows forms, как в Vs?

Tags: c++, windows, clion, forms

В Rider вроде есть winforms, а вот в Clion не завезли, может быть можно как нибудь добавить?

Comment: windows forms - это .NET и C# или С++-cli, но не С++.

Comment: Да я имел в виду CLI

Comment: Поддержки CLI в clion никакой нет.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, понял